# Retrieve user by channel ID?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am retrieving all of the videos for a given channel by:

> 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{username}/uploads'

When I go to a channel, such as: http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXIyz409s7bNWVcM-vjfdVA I have the channel ID and I can quite clearly see the videos. Also, if I click on the 'Videos' tab I can see all the videos, but the URL changes to: http://www.youtube.com/user/majesticcasual/videos

I would like to take the channel ID and retrieve the username for the given channel such that I can query YouTube's API for the videos by channel ID. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you retrieve this feed:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/[channel_id]/
```

You'll get a response that includes an `<author>` element -- the `<name>` child of that `<author>` element is the username. It's also repeated in that same feed as `<yt:username>`.

Of course, that's kind of moot, because you can query by channelID directly:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/[channel_id]/uploads
```

is the same feed as if you'd used the username. This works because the channel_id really is just the unique ID of someone's username.

If you want to use v3 of the API (Which is highly encouraged, as it's at production level now), you could use this feed:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUXIyz409s7bNWVcM-vjfdVA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Note that I've changed the channel id so instead of starting with UC (as all channel ids do), I'm passing in a value that starts with UU ... this is so you get back the uploads feed of the channel (you could also have it start with LL instead to get back the 'likes' feed, for example ... or even do a request to:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&id=UCXIyz409s7bNWVcM-vjfdVA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

To retrieve, in the contentDetails parameter, all of the playlists associated with that particular channel.